# Docker on Win10 - apt-get install returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: php, windows, docker, apt-get

[image]

While building containers I got error, in my case in mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case increse "Disk image size:" in Docker Settings resolved this problem. First I tried **docker pull debian:jessie** but didn't help